# Understanding open source blog engines RaccoonBlog & Subtext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, open-source, ravendb, subtext

I downloaded two open source blog engines ([subtext](http://code.google.com/p/subtext/) and [RaccoonBlog](https://github.com/fitzchak1/RaccoonBlog)) but I can't get any documentation for either of them to develop understanding of the code.

Subtext is setup properly on dev machine and I can create new blogs, posts etc. and there is no problem as far as application setup is concerned. The main problem regarding subtext is that I can't understand its routing mechanism and for that I need some documentation.

For RaccoonBlog, I have problem setting it up on my dev machine. When I try to debug the application it throws an exception at
`IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(Tags_Count).Assembly, DocumentStore)` in DocumentStoreHolder class's initialize method. I believe it has something to do with RavenDb.

I have never worked with RavenDb before.

Comment: Silly question, but do you have a RavenDB instance running for the blog to talk to?

Comment: In fact i don't have RavenDb setup on local machine. thanks for the reply. i will get back after setting up the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a lot of info here http://code.google.com/p/subtext/w/list. Particularly the request lifecycle page.

You might also find some useful info on Phil Haack's blog http://haacked.com/tags/Subtext/default.aspx

Another engine to through into the mix BlogEngine.Net http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/

Answer (score 0):

> can't understand its routing mechanism

What is it your trying to do?  The routing can be found -

http://code.google.com/p/subtext/source/browse/trunk/src/Subtext.Web/Routes.cs